# How can I make a variable to accumulate clicks made over a datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, click

I want to acumulate the number of clicks made of clicks made on a datagridview but I always obtain 1 click

```
    Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles LRInc.CellMouseClick
    MsgBox(e.Clicks & e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: you can use Either CellMouseClick and CellMouseDoubleClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageBox` is displayed when first click occurs and other clicks are ignored. You need to implement another method to show a result.

```
Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.Clicks & e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex)
End Sub
```

Result should be in the Output window.

Alternatively you can create a TextBox (`Text1`) to hold result

```
Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
        Text1.text = e.Clicks & e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex
End Sub
```

**Edit - Accumulation**

Declaration and initialization:

```
Private Accums As New ArrayList
```

Event:

```
Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
  Accums.Add(New Integer() {e.Clicks, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex})
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But, what if I want to have a variable which acumulates the total number of clicks made. The intention is to create a 3 columns array where the first one is the number of click, the second one the e.columnindex and the third the e.rowindex. The first row will have the info related to the first click, second row second click, third row third click and so on

Comment: Thank you IvanH! But, how can I build a 3 columns array where the first one is the number of click, the second one the e.columnindex and the third the e.rowindex. The first row will have the info related to the first click, second row second click, third row third click and so on. If you want it, Ill open a new question for it

Comment: @JoaquínBenavides: Its probably better to have new question. I apologize I still do not understand it fully. The column is 1,2,... up to total number of clicks to whole grid or it is number of click per cell or someting other? But be careful with question not to be marked as duplicate. Or edit the current one. It seems to be a bit complicated to be solved in comments only.

Comment: Don't worry @IvanH, I do appreciate your effort. I have edited the current question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @IvanH: I have created a new question, as we said, called: "How can I make an array to show clicks made over a whole datagridview?" Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

use the event **OnMouseDown** in **DataGridView**

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Clicks == 1)
            {
                // Single Click occurred.
               label1.Text="Single Click";
            }
            if (e.Clicks == 2)
            {
                // Double Click occurred.
                label1.Text = "Double Click";
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay. Although this is nice to know,this is not making a variable to accumulate the clicks made over a datagridview.